# How to program F Keys - UBUNTU 14.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.10

I would like to program the F keys for commands I more often use in Ubuntu. For example, say I want to program F1 to open a directory I use quite often, F2 to Open the Terminal Window which then automatically executes a command, and so on.
How can I do that? 
Thanks much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a software can help like [KeyTouch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keytouch/).

Also, some keybord come with a program for this kind of thing.

Hope this help.